# Not able to connect to my Ubuntu SSH Server even after port forwarding on router

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

I am using a Ubuntu Laptop on a WiFi router. I have installed SSH server on it so that I can access it from my office network. I have forwarded port 7000 from my router settings. Now, when I try to ping the IP address of my router from my office network, I get a reply. However, I am still not able to reach my Ubuntu machine though. What I am missing here? I'd appreciate your answers.

Comment: Are you sure your WiFi router setup allows this?  What about system firewall on the Ubuntu system?  What about any firewall on the Windows system?  Are both ipv4 and ipv6 allowed on all components (Ubuntu, Windows, Wifi Router)?

Comment: I have forwarded the port 7000 in my router. Now I am not sure what to do next.

Answer (score 1):

- You need to make sure your `iptables` rules allow access to the SSH port.
- Your router needs to forward from port 7000 to 22 (the default ssh port).
- In `/etc/hosts.allow`, add the line:

  ```
  ALL: sshd
  ```
- In `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, have the following settings:

  ```
  Port 22

  UsePAM yes
  AllowUsers YOUR_USERNAME_HERE
  ```
- If this does not work, we can try tracing your network and see if that's the problem.
- If you need help configuring iptables to allow access, just ask and we will set that up as well.

Also: Can you send pings out from the Linux box? I.e., `ping google.com` from your Linux laptop.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I have added the hosts.allow and sshd_config file as you said. 

I am not sure how to make change iptable rules and how to forward from port 7000 to 22. Could you please help me with that?